# Derivation of Ito's Lemma (Strong)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Regarding the proof in Thm 1.1, I am confused as to why we can assume that $X_t$ can be substituted into the formula at the top of the image since that formula was derived using a Brownian motion. Is it because the transformation $\mu_tdt +\sigma_tdB_t$ is a Brownian motion too? and if so, how can one show this?

[image]

Comment: That is because Ito calculus applies not only to Brownian motion, but also to general (continuous semimartingale) processes.

Comment: So do all general processes have $(dX_t)^2=dt$

Comment: The equation in the last line is true. But $(dX_t)^2=dt$ is not a general property.

Comment: But doesn't this have to be a property of all S.P. satisfying the theorem?